# Need to make wrapper of .lib, .h and .dll in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wrapper, .lib

I have .h , .lib and dll files. I need to use those files in c# window based project. In .h file, there is defination of class.

I am opening sample project and it gives me error like strmbase.lib linking error.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For C#. For .dll you add [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the project, for .lib file you use [platform invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx)

Comment: i could not add reference as it is created with Visual C++